# How to find the total number of tweets on Twitter for a query term like "Metaverse" more efficiently than snscrape?

Tags: twitter

Hello fellow developers

I am currently using the snscrape library along with the sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query) method to scrape tweets containing a specific query term, like "Metaverse". My goal is to find the total number of tweets on Twitter for this query term, but I find the performance of snscrape to be somewhat slow for this task.

My current code looks like this:

```py
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter

query = "Metaverse"
scraper = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query)

total_tweets = 0
for tweet in scraper.get_items():
    total_tweets += 1
print(f'Total tweets for "{query}": {total_tweets}')
```

Is there a more efficient way to find the total number of tweets on Twitter for a specific query term without having to scrape all the tweets with snscrape?

Answer (score -1):

The method you're currently using with snscrape is a common approach to count the number of tweets for a specific query term. However, as you've noticed, it can be slow because it needs to scrape all the tweets and count them one by one.

Unfortunately, Twitter's (X's) public API does not provide a direct way to get the total number of tweets for a specific query. The search API only returns a subset of recent tweets and does not include a count of total tweets.

However, there are a few alternative approaches you could consider:

Twitter's (X's) Premium or Enterprise APIs: These APIs provide full-archive search functionality, which allows you to search the complete history of public tweets. They also provide the total count of tweets that match your query. However, these APIs are not free and can be quite expensive.

Estimation: If you're only interested in a rough estimate, you could consider scraping a small sample of tweets and then extrapolating to estimate the total number of tweets. This won't give you an exact count, but it could give you a ballpark figure much more quickly than scraping all tweets.

Third-party Services: There are third-party services that provide more advanced Twitter analytics, including tweet counts for specific queries. Examples include Brandwatch and Sprout Social. These services are not free, but they may be more efficient and provide additional functionality compared to direct scraping.

Parallelization: If you want to stick with snscrape and you're comfortable with more advanced programming techniques, you could consider parallelizing your scraping process to speed it up. This would involve running multiple instances of your scraper in parallel, each scraping a different subset of tweets. This can be complex to set up and may increase your risk of hitting Twitter's (X's) rate limits.

Remember, any method of scraping or accessing Twitter (X) data should comply with Twitter's (X's) terms of service, including respect for their rate limits and rules about data usage.

Hope this helps!

-$